# SATA/SSD at the same time

Tags: grub2, hard-drive

I know that one requeriment to do this it's the laptop, it has to support two medias.

But my doubt is this:

Mounting a scenario: I have a laptop, it supports two medias, I want to install Windows in SATA 500G and GNU/Linux in  SSD 128G.

**Is that possible? Will the grub show both? Do i have to do an extra configuration?**

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. You are describing a standard setup, why would you expect problems? What do you mean by "extra" configuration? Extra as in more than a normal dual boot? This *is* a normal dual boot. Or are you asking how to dual boot in general?

Comment: SSD drives are often connected via SATA (like hard disk drives). Both kinds of drives can also be connected via an external box to USB (and USB 3 is much faster than USB 3). Can you connect your SSD via SATA, eSATA or USB? (I assume that you intend to install Windows in an internal SATA hard disk drive.) Please edit your original question to answer to these questions and assumptions.

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.